# Adding * to some section numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, section-titles

How to add * to some (i.e. not all) section numbers?

—

**Before**

2.1 Differentiation

2.2 Integration

**After**

2.1 Differentiation

2.2* Integration

—

- The documentclass is jlreq.
- I don’t want to use a package because it can break the style.
- I need the starred sections to be included in a table of contents.
- There will be cross-references to some of starred sections. The section number should be displayed in the cross-reference with the asterisk.

—

**Small sample document**

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[book]{jlreq}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Calculus}
\section{Differentiation}
\section{Integration}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The `jlreq` class is quite non-standard relative to other classes since it's designed for Japanese typesetting. It would be helpful to add a small sample document using the class for people to play with. Do you need the starred sections to be included in a table of contents?

Comment: Should the asterisk markers be present just in the sectioning headers? Will there be cross-references to some of "starred" sections? If so, how should the section number be displayed in the cross-reference: with or without the asterisk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a conditional and mark “difficult” sections with

```
\section+{Title}
```

This also allows the standard optional argument to `\section`, so you can still do

```
\section+[Short title]{Long title}
```

as usual. A `\label` can go anywhere: inside the main argument or also outside. Also `\section*` will work as usual.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsection}{\section}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{t+sO{#4}m}{%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\difficultsectiontrue}
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    % called as \section*
    \latexsection*{#4}%
  }{%
    \latexsection[#3]{#4}%
  }%
  \difficultsectionfalse
}
\newif\ifdifficultsection
\renewcommand{\thesection}{%
  \thechapter.\arabic{section}%
  \ifdifficultsection *\fi
}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{%
  \thechapter.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Calculus}

We have section~\ref{diff} and section~\ref{int}

\section{Differentiation}\label{diff}
\subsection{Preliminaries}
\section+{Integration}\label{int}
\subsection{Preliminaries}

\end{document}
```

I also redefined `\thesubsection` so it won't have a `*`.

Production note: the first three lines in the above code are only aimed to obtain a smaller picture of the output.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution which sets up a new command, `\starredsection`. It meets all four of the OP's requirements. Its limitations are (a) any `\label` command must be included in the argument of `\starredsection` and (b) no optional argument is recognized.

The ToC page:

[image]

The first main page:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[book]{jlreq}

\newcommand\starredsection[1]{%
   \begingroup % localize scope of next instruction
   \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}*}
   \section{#1}
   \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Calculus}

\section{Differentiation}
\starredsection{Integration\label{sec:integ}}
\subsection{Hello}
\section{Whatever}\label{sec:what}

\noindent
Cross-references to sections \ref{sec:integ} and \ref{sec:what}.

\end{document}
```